# How do I build a list of parameters for an executable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a snippet of Powershell where I need to call an external executable, with a list of switches.

```
& $pathToExe 
        --project $project `
        --server $server `
        --apiKey $key `
```

Now I need to do something like "if `$someVariable -eq $True` then also add `--optionalSwitch $someValue`".

How can I do this without a load of repetition? For reference the real exe call is much bigger than this, and the list of optional switches is larger!

Comment: Will the exe accept arguments in the form `--project:$project --server:$server` (`:` rather than spaces between switches and arguments) - if so, it's trivial with splatting

Comment: It accepts '=' for some arguments, but there are others which don't have any associated value like `--debug`. Would your suggestion still work for those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a hashtable that contains parameters and their values? Like so,

```
$ht = @{}
$ht.Add('project', 'myProject') 
$ht.Add('apikey', $null) 
$ht.Add('server', 'myServer')
```

To build the parameter string, filter the collection by excluding keys without values:

```
$pop = $ht.getenumerator() | ? { $_.value -ne $null }
```

Build the command string by iterating the filtered collection

```
$cmdLine = "myExe"
$pop | % { $cmdLine += " --" + $_.name + " " + $_.value }
# Check the result
$cmdLine
myExe --server myServer --project myProject
```